# Trouble running Ex commands after normal mode commands in a macro

Tags: gvim, macro

I have the following macro:

```
ggdG"+p
:try|%s/\V${NodeName}/${N=SwisEntity;M=DisplayName}/|catch||endtry
:try|%s/\V${IP}/${N=SwisEntity;M=IP_Address}/|catch||endtry
:try|%s/\V${IP_Address}/${N=SwisEntity;M=IP_Address}/|catch||endtry
:try|%s/\V${Status}/${N=SwisEntity;M=Status;F=Status}/|catch||endtry
:try|%s/\V${location}/${N=SwisEntity;M=Location}/|catch||endtry
:try|%s/\V${AdminStatus}/${N=SwisEntity;M=AdminStatus}/|catch||endtry
gg"+yG
```

The goal is to delete the contents of the buffer, paste the text from the system clipboard, execute the substitutions, and yank the contents of the buffer back to the system clipboard.

The pieces all work individually. If I execute the first line as a macro by itself (`ggdG"+p`), and then execute the rest as a separate macro, the whole thing works as expected.

However, when I execute the whole block as a single macro, it seems to only execute the first line. It doesn't preform the substitutions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to use instead of this `:try|%s/\V${NodeName}/${N=SwisEntity;M=DisplayName}/|catch||endtry` use `%s/.../e` (The `e` flag is for ignoring errors, I assume you don't need the `g` flag?) BTW: I would create a function out of this and run the function, instead of using a macro, easier to understand and maintain

Comment: Yeah, I gotta second that. This is the ugliest macro I think I've seen. ;) Do yourself a favor and put it in a function.

Comment: Macros will stop on the first error, which maybe try isn’t preventing here. Christian’s `/e` flag is the usual idiom for substituting and ignoring errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `e`, that is much nicer, although it didn't fix the problem.

Rewriting it as a function does seem to have worked, so thanks for that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity when you try it when running Vim with flag `-u DEFAULTS` does it make any difference? It works for me that way...